# Bootstrap group button form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using sb-admin template and I'm stuck at my form in the sidebar because of the group button extending below. The original code is this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
 <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
 </button>
</span>
```

And the output is:

[image]

But when I add a form tag:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
     </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

It becomes like this:

[image]

Is there a fast fix for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `<div class="input-group">` before your `input` field.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </span>

    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's A way to do that, but you will need to use CSS to adjust the `padding/height` of either the `input` or `button` or `both` so that they are equal.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nkyysb93/)

```
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```